# React, Redux Form: Change handler does not allow flipping of passed arguments in any manner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I encountered a quite strange issue recently. I have a class component in react which uses redux form. `onChange` event handler is called in case the input checkbox is toggled. Two arguments `value` and `type`(name of input) is passed to the event handler. When I console log the `value` it is properly showing the previous value. However, I cannot flip this boolean value in any manner i.e. the expression `!value` or `let value = value?false:true` always returns true/false depending on the initial state irrespective of the current state. I searched on the google & SO to find the cause but unable to find the same. Any kind of help is deeply appreciated.

Here is the code for your reference

```
class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: true
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };

  handleChange(value, type) {
    console.log(value); //outputs previous value (before toggle)
    let currValue = value ? false:true; //this line is not working
    console.log(currValue); //outputs the same value (irrespective of state)
  } 

  render() {
   return (
      <div>
        <Field component="input" type="checkbox" name="name" id="name"
      onChange={({target}) => this.handleChange(target.value,target.name)}/> Name
      </div>
     );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return state;
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({change},dispatch);
}

export default compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: 'example', key: 'example',
    initialValues: {
      name: true
    },
    enableReinitialize: true
  }),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(Example);
```

**Output (toggled twice: intial state checked)**

[image: Console Output]

Comment: what is the type of `value` is it string or boolean ?

Comment: @Ali Oops! it comes out to be a string. I got the reason. Thank you so much. It is a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because the type of `value` is string your flip statement not working as you want

since `"false"` is consider to be true value.

```js
console.log(Boolean("false"));
```

```
let currValue = false;
if(value == "false")
    currValue = true;
```

your function should look like this

```
handleChange(value, type) {
    console.log(value); 
    let currValue = false;
    if(value == "false")
        currValue = true;
    console.log(currValue); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the value for `Field`. So, you'll need to set the value:

```
<Field 
  component="input" 
  type="checkbox" 
  name="name" 
  id="name"
  onChange={({target}) => this.handleChange(target.value,target.name)}
  value={this.state.name || true}
/>
```

The handler:

```
handleChange(value, type) {
  this.setState({[type]: !value})
}
```